# Creating S3 policy with terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, policy

I am trying to create a S3 bucket and apply a policy to it. Bucket creation steps are fine and when I am trying to apply the below policy I am not able to find the bug in this tf file

The terraform version is - Terraform v0.12.23

```
{
        "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedConnection",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": [
             "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucketName}",
             "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucketName}/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "Bool": {
                "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
            }
        }
    }
```

In my main.tf file this is what I am passing to the variable

```
  module "s3-bucket-policy" {
  source                            = "../s3-policy/"
  s3_bucketName                     = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id}"
  bucket_arn                        = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.arn}"
....
```

The terraform plan command is giving me the policy as below.(Running it through a Jenkins job Copied out of Jenkins log)

```
    module.s3_bucket.module.s3-bucket-policy.aws_s3_bucket_policy.communication_policy[0][0m will be created[0m[0m
00:00:07.805 [0m  [32m+[0m[0m resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "communication_policy" {
00:00:07.805       [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mbucket[0m[0m = (known after apply)
00:00:07.805       [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mid[0m[0m     = (known after apply)
00:00:07.805       [32m+[0m [0m[1m[0mpolicy[0m[0m = (known after apply)
00:00:07.805     }
```

But when I try to apply the same getting the below error and I am not sure how to proceed further.

```
 [31m
00:01:13.117 [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement
00:01:13.117    status code: 400, [0m
00:01:13.117
```

Any pointers on this will be very much appreciated

Comment: Double check the S3 bucket name and ARN. They should match the target bucket.

Comment: I verified them in short I hard bound all the values and even tried that @jellycsc still no luck

Comment: Can you provide complete example of how do you apply the policy?

Comment: I have a script which assumes role and exports the values to the env and the tf commands follow it as below.


terraform init
terraform validate
terraform plan -var-file=$file -input=false
terraform apply -var-file=$file -auto-approve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply a proper `Action` compatible with your bucket, change your policy to the following and it should work:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"

  acl    = "public-read"
  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyUnEncryptedConnection",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

(I changed the resource to use `bucket_arn` but it should work with `s3_bucketName` the way you did it too.)

Note the `"Action": "s3:*"`, this policy explicitly denies all [actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations.html) on the bucket and objects when the request meets the condition `"aws:SecureTransport": "false"` (i.e. it's not an HTTPS connection).

Comment: This didn't work. I am still getting the same error

Comment: I've updated it with a tested full working example, this applies the policy directly in the TF `aws_s3_bucket` resource. Please share the code of your module `s3-bucket-policy`, I guess you're using `aws_s3_bucket_policy`? Are you sure you're passing in a correct bucket ARN? We won't be able to help you unless you share the full code so that we can reproduce it.